# Recovering composition in enriched categories from tensors

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Let $(\mathcal{V},\otimes,e)$ be a closed symmetric monoidal category and $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$ a tensored  $\mathcal{V}$-category. We will write $\mathcal{A}$ for the underlying category of $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$. I was wondering whether the $\mathcal{V}$-natural isomorphism
$$\underline{\mathcal{V}}(v,\underline{\mathcal{A}}(a,b))\cong \underline{\mathcal{A}}(v\otimes a ,b)$$
retains enough information to recover the identities and the compositions in $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$. More specifically, I want to show that the identity $e\to \underline{\mathcal{A}}(a,a)$ is the transpose of the isomorphism $e\otimes a\cong a$, and the composition $\underline{\mathcal{A}}(b,c)\otimes \underline{\mathcal{A}}(a,b)\to\underline{\mathcal{A}}(a,c)$ is the transpose of the composition $$\underline{\mathcal{A}}(b,c)\otimes \underline{\mathcal{A}}(a,b)\otimes a \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}\otimes \epsilon_{a,b}}\underline{\mathcal{A}}(b,c)\otimes b\xrightarrow{\epsilon_{b,c}}c,$$
where $\epsilon_{a,b}$ is the transpose of the identity.

Assuming that the composition map $c_{a,b,c}$ is indeed equal to the above description, I was able to deduce that the identity has to be given by the above description. (I used the induced natural isomorphism $\mathcal{V}(e,\underline{\mathcal{A}}(a,b))\cong\mathcal{A}(e\otimes a,b)$ and the uniqueness of identity.) However, I cannot manage to prove that the $c_{a,b,c}$ is given as above (except in the trivial case $\mathcal{V}=\mathsf{Set}$). Can someone help me? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\mathcal V$ is not assumed to be a *concrete* category then the underlying category might not even exist in the first place.

Comment: @Berci  I'm afraid I don't understand your comment completely. By the underlying category of $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$, I mean the base change of $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$ along the monoidal functor $\mathcal{V}(e,-):\mathcal{V}\to\mathsf{Set}$.  I apologize if there was any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{AMScd}$
(After nineteen months...)

This is true if $\mathcal{V}$ is cartesian monoidal, which was the case I was interested in. (I'm still interested in the general case, though.) While the proof is straightforward once we identify what to do, I will sketch it below anyway. Since the assertion on the identity map is obvious from the definitions, I will focus on the assertion on the composition map.

To ease notation, I will modify the notation a little bit and write $\mathcal{A}$ instead of $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$. I will also use capital letters to denote objects in categories, and let $[-,-]$ denote the internal hom of $\mathcal{V}$. I will write $\ast$ for the terminal object of $\mathcal{V}$.

---

### Step 1

For each object $V\in \mathcal{V}$, let $\mathcal{A}_V$ denote the ordinary category with the same set of objects as $\mathcal{A}$, and with hom-sets given by $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}_V}(A,B)=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{V}}(V,\mathcal{A}(A,B))$. We will refer to morphisms of $A$ as **$V$-morphisms**. Note that each morphism $u:V\to W$ in $\mathcal{V}$ induces a functor $u^*:\mathcal{A}_W\to\mathcal{A}_V$, and that $\mathcal{A}_\ast$, by definition, is the underlying category of $\mathcal{A}$.

Since $\mathcal{A}$ is tensored, each object $V\in \mathcal{A}$ has a distinguished $V$-morphism $\eta _A:A\to V\otimes A$ satisfying the following property: For each $V$-morphism $f:A\to B$, there is a unique $\ast$-morphism $f^+:V\otimes A\to B$ rendering the diagram

\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> B\\
@V{\eta_A}VV @|\\
V\otimes A @>>{p^*(f^+)}> B
\end{CD}

commutative, where $p:V\to\ast$ denotes the unique map to the terminal object. We claim that:

> ($\star$) Given $V$-morphisms $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$, the $\ast$-morphism $(g\circ f)^+:V\otimes A\to B$ is given by the composite
> $$V\otimes A\xrightarrow{\delta\otimes A}
> (V\times V)\otimes A \xrightarrow{\cong}
> V\otimes(V\otimes A) \xrightarrow{V\otimes f^+}
> V\otimes B \xrightarrow{g^+}
> C,
> $$
> where $\delta$ denotes the diagonal.

Claim ($\ast$) follows from claims (1) and (2) below, whose proofs are easy diagram chase:

> (1) For each $\ast$-morphism $f:A\to B$, the diagram
> \begin{CD}
> A @>{p^*(f)}>> B\\
> @V{\eta_A}VV @VV{\eta_B}V\\
> V\otimes A @>>{V\otimes p^*(f)}> V\otimes B
> \end{CD}
> is commutative.

> (2) For each object $A\in \mathcal{A}$, the diagram
> \begin{CD}
> V\otimes A @<{\eta_A}<< A @>{\eta_A}>> V\otimes A\\
> @V{\delta\otimes A}VV @. @VV{\eta_{V\otimes A}}V\\
> (V\times V)\otimes A @>>{\cong}> V\otimes (V\otimes A) @=V\otimes (V\otimes A)
> \end{CD}
> commutes.

---

### Step 2

We now prove the assertion on the composition map. Let $A,B,C\in \mathcal{A}$. We wish to show that the diagram

\begin{CD}
(\mathcal{A}(B,C)\times \mathcal{A}(A,B))\otimes A 
@>{\cong}>>\mathcal{A}(B,C)\otimes (\mathcal{A}(A,B)\otimes A)
@>>>\mathcal{A}(B,C)\otimes B\\
@VVV @. @VVV\\
\mathcal{A}(A,C)\otimes A @>>> C @= C
\end{CD}

commutes. For this, set $V=\mathcal{A}(A,B)\times \mathcal{A}(B,C)$. The projections $V\to \mathcal{A}(A,B),\mathcal{A}(B,C)$ determine $V$-morphisms $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$. Unwinding the definitions, we deduce that the commutativity of the above diagram is equivalent to the assertion that the $\ast$-morphism $(g\circ f)^+:V\otimes A\to C$ is given by the formula in claim ($\star$). This completes Step 2.